# Youtube Won't Let Me Sign In.

Tags: youtube

Youtube won't let me sign in. Let me explain. I was putting in my username and clicked Next or pressed enter. It just did nothing. Like it wouldn't let me sign in. I removed the cookies and cache and disabled anything that would be causing it but nothing works. But this only happens in Mozilla Firefox. Everywhere else is fine. Please help.

Comment: If it only fails in Firefox, then it would seem there's an issue with your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a refresh of your browser, maybe something went wrong during an update.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Before you go for that, you could also try to access/login the page in safe mode, if that works, it is more than likely that you can resolve your problem with refresh.